# dotnet nuget ssl problem on linux azure devops

Tags: .net, ubuntu, azure-devops, nuget, restore

I trying to build dotnet project on ubuntu 18.04. I have some some nuget packets stored on local Azure Devops server repository. I have https and self-signed certificate configured. I added source via

`dotnet nuget add source https://myurl/nuget/v3/index.json --name Int1 --username myuser --password mypasswd --store-password-in-clear-text --configfile nuget.config`

When i try to perform restore i've got the following error:

`/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.201/NuGet.targets(124,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://myurl/nuget/v3/index.json. [/home/Frontend/myproject.sln]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.201/NuGet.targets(124,5): error :   The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. [/home/Frontend/myproject.sln]
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.201/NuGet.targets(124,5): error :   The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure. [/home/Frontend/myproject.sln]`

I put https://myurl/ to a browser, downloaded the .pem certificate , put it into `/usr/share/ca-certificates/` and made `dkpg-reconfigure ca-certificates` but it's still gives an error.

Curl is not working too.

`curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html`

`curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.`

On Windows if I place my certificate as root trusted everything works fine. Is where any way to do the same on linux ?

Comment: Hi, Did you get a chance to try out below solution. How did it go?

Answer (score 0):

To install .pem certificate on Ubuntu, you might need to convert .pem certificate to .crt certificate first.

You can use below command to convert .pem certificate to .crt certificate.

`openssl x509 -outform der -in CERTIFICATE.pem -out CERTIFICATE.crt`

Then Copy .crt into the proper location:

`sudo cp CERTIFICATE.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificate`

And then update your certificate with below command:

`sudo update-ca-certificates`

You can check out [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73287/how-do-i-install-a-root-certificate) for more information.